# Why is stripe using PHP slim

Tags: php, slim, stripe-payments

is there a specific reason why stripe uses PHP SLIM on the subscription page for webhooks?
Link: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/elements

I have never heared of PHP SLIM before and would be interested to know if you could just use plain old php without having to reinvent the wheel?

Greetings,
John

Comment: Where are they using SLIM exactly…?! And yes, surely you can use plain PHP as well.

Comment: On there linked Github sample: https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/blob/master/fixed-price-subscriptions/server/php-slim/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use plain PHP for this purpose. They use SLIM just because it looks better and examples will look shorter